# Why does 9-patch does not work on wallpapers?

Tags: android, wallpaper, nine-patch

I had a small image 250x208 (size decreased from 960x800) and made 9.png out of it. Set it as a wallpaper image via `wallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.my_wallpaper);` but it is still getting stretched incorrectly like this is not 9-patch image.

Why 9-patch does not size correctly as a wallpaper?

What do you do when you have an app that has to set some image as a wallpaper?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about the wallpaper on the homescreen? or a background for the layout in your application?

Comment: Wallpaper on the mobile desktop, home screen. like live wallpaper, but just a regular wallpaper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that `WallpaperManager` supports nine-patches, so you may need to render the nine-patch yourself using a live wallpaper.

---

**EDIT**: removed since the question was changed.

<strike>You should just use a `View` with an `android:background` set to the nine-patch. There's no need to use an `ImageView` with all its fancy custom image scaling logic for a background image.</strike>

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong part of the code. I will repair it asap.

Comment: Can I set/install Live Wallpaper programmatically? I set this wallpaper from withing the Android app.

Comment: No, I don't believe there's *currently* a mechanism to set a Live Wallpaper programmatically.

Comment: @RomanNurik, will plain png files get scaled as well or only 9patches exclusively?